# I need to cache a TemplateView with a querystring - how?

Tags: django, caching, query-string

Basically, I'm trying to cache a simple search results page (generated with a TemplateView view) with a URL pattern of:

/search/?q=foo

I've tried:

- @cache_page  - doesn't work with querystrings (why? the stated reason "querystrings *usually* do not affect the results" completely depends on 'usually' meaning 'always' which is demonstrably false);
- django-fancy-cache  - doesn't work with CBVs (but in principle appears to do exactly what I want);
- Adjusting the action on my form with an onSubmit() to change the url pattern (so that there's no querystring) - for SOME reason this messes up every other page on the site even though the test form doesn't exist on any of those pages.

I can't be the first person in the universe who needs this  :-)  ...  Pointers to something I've missed in the Django docs or to a package that has eluded my search for it GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) for that purpose, using the query string to uniquely identify the cache fragment. In  your template:

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 3600 search_results request.META.QUERY_STRING %}
    <!-- search results here -->
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: I had considered that, but to get to the template, you still have to re-run the view, and it's THAT code I'm trying to avoid.

(The view does an expensive API call.)

Or am I misunderstanding the order of how things get rendered?

Comment: As long as Django has the appropriate template fragment cached, it should not re-evaluate variables necessary to generate it.